# Значение по умолчанию при инициализации полей объекта в C#

Tags: c#, .net, clr

В MSDN нашел такое

> Если класс не содержит конструктор, автоматически создается конструктор по умолчанию и для инициализации полей объекта используются значения по умолчанию. Например, int инициализируется значением 0.

Если конструктр по умолчанию инициализурет переменные как значения по умолчанию, то почему при создании другого конструктора, тоже другие переменные инициализуруются как 0 (или null)? Например, если в классе 3 переменных, и в конструкторе установливается значение для двоих, то третий принимает значение по умолчанию. По словам microsoft, конструктор по умолчанию делает это. А как эта инициализация происходит, если в конструкторе мы это не указали?

Comment: Тут надо понять чем отличается `ValueType` от `ReferenceType`. `ValueType` не может быть `null`, так `int` всегда по умолчанию имеет значение 0

Comment: @Chloroform вы не поняли вопрос. вопрос не в этом ...

Comment: Если я напишу: `int` всегда инициализируется значением 0. Так понятнее? 
Конструктор класса тут не причём

Comment: Скажем так, вы ищите проблему там, где её нет. Раз уж вы хотите в логику, то в определении написано, что: нет конструктора => автоматический конструктор & значения по умолчанию. Делаем отрицание: есть конструктор => нет автоматического конструктора | значения не по-умолчанию. В данном случае меняется только одно условие "наличие автоматического условия".

Comment: Потому что при компиляции и в эти другие конструкторы вставляются инициализирующие конструкции, а не только в конструктор по умолчанию.

Comment: Подробнее смотри допустим в книге  Рихтера в главе 8 Методы: Генерируя IL-код для трех методов-конструкторов из этого примера, компилятор помещает в начало _каждого_ из методов код, инициализирующий поля m_x, m_s и m_d.

Comment: @AK а если в классе мы указали public string Name = "Something". Тогда при при создании объекта в конструкторе неявно значение присваивается ? (То есть ctor(){Name = "Something";})

Answer (score 1):

Конструктор не может вернуть наполовину созданный объект. Те поля, которые вы не инициализируете вручную, будут инициализированы автоматически. Поля ссылочного типа - нулевыми ссылками, а поля типов значений - значениями по умолчанию (0 для int, например).

Answer (score 1):

Вы не на том акцентируете внимание. Конструктор нужен не только для того, чтобы инициализировать поля класса, а еще и для того для того, чтобы просто банально создавать объект. Поэтому и существует конструктор по умолчанию.